# Use for loop to create mulitiple variables?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to use for loop to create multiple variables.
I want to create

```
var node0 = document.getElementById("refresh_table_0");
node0.innerHTML="";
var node1 = document.getElementById("refresh_table_1");
node1.innerHTML="";
var node2 = document.getElementById("refresh_table_2");
node2.innerHTML="";
```

this is my imagination code:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
var node+i = document.getElementById("refresh_table_i");
node+i.innerHTML="";
}
```

Comment: Any time you think you want a bunch of numbered variables, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. You should use an array. And if you think you need dynamically-named variables, you should use an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just initialize all the items, you can simply do this as there's no need to retain each separate DOM object:

```
var node;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    node = document.getElementById("refresh_table_" + i);
    node.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Or, even just this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById("refresh_table_" + i).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this is javascript. 
Second, the imagined code has errors, should be ("refresh_table_" + i).

Try using js arrays instead.

```
var node = new Array();
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    node[i] = document.getElementById("refresh_table_" + i);
    node[i].innerHTML="";
}
```